Set variable output in different stages in azure devops pipeline
Im trying to get the _id from the database and i want to set it as variable to use in different stages but unable to get the id from record variable ex: api, error Logs update with success details: {"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}.
I belive am not setting the pipeline variable for recordId. Please assist me to resolve this issue.
######################
#DECLARE PARAMETERS:-
######################
parameters:
- name: ResourceGroup
  displayName: Please Provide the Resource Group Name:-
  type: string
 
- name: Location
  displayName: Please Provide the Location:-
  type: string
  default: <Please provide the required location>
- name: Virtual_Network
  displayName: Please Provide the Virtual_Network Name:-
  type: object
  
- name: Subnet
  displayName: Please Provide the subnet name:-
  type: object
 - name: Network_Interface
  displayName: Please Provide the NIC name:-
  type: object
  
- name: TicketNumber
  displayName: Please Provide the Number:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name> 

- name: TicketSysID
  displayName: Please Provide the sysid:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name> 


######################
#DECLARE VARIABLES:-
######################
variables:
  TF_VAR_RESOURCEGROUP: ${{ parameters.ResourceGroup }}
  TF_VAR_LOCATION: ${{ parameters.Location }} 
  TF_VAR_VIRTUAL_NETWORK: ${{ parameters.Virtual_Network }}
  TF_VAR_SUBNET: ${{ parameters.Subnet }}
  TF_VAR_BU: ${{ parameters.Bu }}

###################
# Declare Stages:-
###################
stages:
- stage: UpdateStatus
  jobs:
      - job: UpdateTriggeredStatus
        steps:
          - script: |
              # Send "triggered" status to the API endpoint
              response=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "TicketNumber": "${{ parameters.TicketNumber }}", "TicketSysID": "${{ parameters.TicketSysID }}", "TicketRequestor": "xy.com", "TicketRequestorSysID": "3Dd1b5ab66dbeed51027293313e29619ee", "Cloud": "Azure", "UseCase": "MarkLogic", "Status": "New", "Logs": "NA" }' http:/kcmapi:8006/ticket_details/)
              recordId=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.data._id')
              echo "Record ID: $recordId"
              # Extract the "message" field from the JSON response
              message=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.message')

              if [[ "$message" == "Data name updated successfully" ]]; then
                echo "Status update to triggered was successful!"
              else
                echo "Status update to triggered failed with message: $message"
              fi

              # Print the full response for debugging
              echo "Response: $response"
              # Set the recordId as a pipeline variable
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=recordId;isOutput=true]$recordId"
            displayName: Update Status to DB
            name: UpdateTriggeredStatusJob
- stage: tfvalidate
  jobs:
      - job: validate
        continueOnError: false
        steps:
          - task: TerraformInstaller@0
            inputs:
              terraformVersion: 'latest'

          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: init
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'init'
              workingDirectory: 'LaunchStack/terraform/azure/testmarklogic'
              backendServiceArm: '_OIDC_TEST'
              backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
              backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(StorageAccount)
              backendAzureRmContainerName: $(Container)
              backendAzureRmKey: $(TfstateFile)
          
          
- stage: tfdeploy
  condition: succeeded('tfvalidate')
  dependsOn: 
  - UpdateStatus
  - tfvalidate
  jobs:
      - job: apply
        steps: 
          - task: TerraformInstaller@0
            inputs:
              terraformVersion: 'latest'
           
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3  
            displayName: init
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'init'
              workingDirectory: 'LaunchStack/terraform/azure/testmarklogic'
                                     
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: validate
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'validate'
              workingDirectory: 'LaunchStack/terraform/azure/testmarklogic'
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: plan
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'plan'
              workingDirectory: 'LaunchStack/terraform/azure/testmarklogic'
              environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'SaaS_Automationaccount_OIDC_TEST'
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: apply
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'apply'
              workingDirectory: 'LaunchStack/terraform/azure/testmarklogic'
              
              commandOptions: '-auto-approve'
              
              environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'SaaS_Automationaccount_OIDC_TEST' 

          - script: |
              echo "Job Status: $(Agent.JobStatus)"
              echo "Record ID: $(recordId)"
              if [ "$(Agent.JobStatus)" == "Succeeded" ]; then
                # If job is successful, update the Logs status to "success"
                #Concatenate the recordId into the URl
                response=$(curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "TicketNumber": "${{ parameters.TicketNumber }}", "Status": "Success", "Logs": "Pipeline executed Successfully" }' http://compute.amazonaws.com:800/ticket_details/$(recordId))
                echo "Logs update with success details: $response"
                echo "Status update to success was successful!"
              else
                # If job fails, extract error details and update the Logs status
                error_message=$(echo "Error: Error occurred during the job execution on running Terraform plan and apply.")
                logs_response=$(curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "TicketNumber": "${{ parameters.TicketNumber }}", "Status": "Failed", "Logs": "'"$error_message"'" }' http:compute.amazonaws.com:800/ticket_details/$(recordId))
                echo "Logs update with error details: $logs_response"
                echo "Status update to failed with error details: $error_message"
              fi
              echo "Record ID: $recordId"                       
                
            displayName: Print Job Status and Post to MongoDB API 
            condition: always()


As shown by @RuiJarimba, please fix the variable definition in next stage so that $(newRecordId) can be used. Let us know if you have any queries, glad to help.

Example of setting and using an output variable in a different stage:
trigger: none

stages:
  - stage: UpdateStatus
    jobs:
      - job: UpdateTriggeredStatus
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              recordId=123456
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=recordId;isOutput=true]$recordId"
            displayName: Update Status to DB
            name: UpdateTriggeredStatusJob

  - stage: PrintOutput
    dependsOn: UpdateStatus
    jobs:
      - job: PrintOutputJob
        variables:
          # newRecordId: $[ stageDependencies.{stage-name}.{job-name}.outputs['{task-name}.{output-variable-name}'] ] 
          newRecordId: $[ stageDependencies.UpdateStatus.UpdateTriggeredStatus.outputs['UpdateTriggeredStatusJob.recordId'] ]
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: echo $(newRecordId)
            displayName: Print Output Variable

Please note that the syntax to reference an output variable might change, depending on whether you'll use it in the same job or different jobs/stages.
See Levels of output variables for more details.

Thanks @rui jarimba for the response thats helps my issue, in case as above provided script on the stage-tfdeploy i want to use the recordId in the task after terraform apply -script
